# Geocoding Google API NAD83

Tags: google-maps, gps, coordinates, geocoding

I am trying to geocode some addresses. But Google's geocoding only gives me WGS84 type like coordinates. I was wondering if there was a way to get NAD83 coordinates instead.

I have discovered some websites that do the conversion (and they work well) but I have not found a way to automate the process (expect using selenium, but it would be very long as I would like to convert a few hundred thousand GPS coordinates).

Would anyone have an idea?

Best,
Antoine

Answer (score 0):

For NAD83 just use it as WGS84.
NAD83 in the beginning was compatible to WGS84, but since then WGS84 drift about 1 - 2 cm per year.
So you can today expect an offset of 1-2m from WGS84.
You can ignore that for geocoding.

NAD83 coordinates are static and bound to North America.
Such a coordinate for a specific location never changes.
A WGS84 is not bound to any country, and because the continents drift, while WGS84 stays, a location on earth changes its WGS84 coordinate over time.

The NAD27, you luckily do not use, has much more offset.

Comment: Thank you! The issue I am facing is that I need them to actually be that precise (unfortunately...)

Comment: Which geocoding service you want to use? Which coordinate they use? Does they use NAD83? If they use WGS84 they have less precision, they do not care on some meters. A WGS84 coordinate always needs a recording date, otherwise cm precision can never be achieved. For cm precision you must know what you do.   I doubt that you know that.So i doubt that there is a cm acurate requirement.

Comment: If you use Google, the use WGS84. And then you dont have cm precision, So i doubt your requirements on precision are correct. Overthink the whole tool chain, which service has which precision.

Comment: I am trying to link addresses together. A few thousand of them actually. And the addresses I've got are geocoded with 6 decimal points (and some are pretty close so the decimal point is needed). So unfortunately, I do need a precision to the meter.

Comment: the number of decimal points shows the precision, not the accuracy. NAD83 is considered to be equivalent to WGS84 for most applications. If you think different, then ask yourself what is the accuracy of the geocoding service? Do you have the date when the location of the WGS84 coordinate are recorded? Without the date, you cannot transform, because the continent moves while WGS84 stays, the effect is that a location changes its WGS84 coordinates slightly over time, while the NAd83 alsways stays the same,